# Convert an activeworkbook on xlsx to put in an email

Tags: excel, vba

I have a mail service who is good and i want to put my active workbook on my mail but not on xlsm, i want on xlsx.

I tried a solution but the convertion don't work (error).

My code :

```
Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()

Dim TheMail As Variant
Dim Path_name As String
Dim File_name As String
Dim Complete_File_name As String


Set LeMail = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

File_name = ActiveWorkbook.Name
File_name , FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
Path_name = ThisWorkbook.Path
Complete_File_name = Path_name & "\" & File_name

With TheMail.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    .Subject = "Prerequisite"
    .To = ""
    .Body = ""
    .Attachments.Add Complete_File_name & ".xlsx"
    .Display
End With
End Sub
```

Thanks you for all of your response,
Have a nice day !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot simple add a xlsx extension! They are two different workbooks. You should firstly save it as xlsx, to make the conversion you are talking about. Anyhow, a file having the name you try attaching does not even exist...

Please, use the next way:

```
Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()
 Dim TheMail As Variant, Path_name As String, File_name As String
 Dim Complete_File_name As String

 Set TheMail = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

   File_name = ActiveWorkbook.name
   Path_name = ThisWorkbook.path
   Complete_File_name = Path_name & "\" & left(File_name, InStrRev(File_name, ".") - 1) & ".xlsx"
   ActiveWorkbook.saveas Complete_File_name, xlWorkbookDefault

 With TheMail.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    .Subject = "Prerequisite"
    .To = ""
    .body = ""
    .Attachments.Add Complete_File_name
    .Display
 End With
End Sub
```

If you do not need the 'converted' xlsx file, you can delete it. After closing, or use `SaveCopyAs` instead of `saveAs`, to not be necessary to close it.